# angular2 promises observables and DI

Tags: angular, angular2-meteor

If I have a service that looks like this

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  search(oSrchParams){

    let promise = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      Meteor.call('mockSearchWS', (error:any, result:any) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    );

    promise().then(
      (result:Array<Object>) => {
        return result
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('failed', error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

How can I call it and get a value when it is injected?  Like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyService} from './my-service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component ({
  selector: 'search',
  providers:[MyService]
})

export class App {
  items: Array<string>;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
 }

 search(term) {
    // this.myService.search(term).then(items => this.items = items);
    // this.myService.search(term).subscribe()
  }
}
```

I'm not sure whether the service is an observable.  Most examples I've seen use http.

Comment: If you thinking about to make it working to return promise like `return promise().then(`

Comment: are  you using Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the promise in your search method:

```
  search(oSrchParams){

    let promise = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      Meteor.call('mockSearchWS', (error:any, result:any) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    );

    return promise().then(
      (result:Array<Object>) => {
        return result
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('failed', error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

This way you'll be able to call the then in the component that calls this method:

```
 search(term) {
    this.myService.search(term).then(items => this.items = items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  Ok, I was going to put some code here but this doesn't have multi line ... duh

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of things for anyone finding their way here.  I included a type for the method

```
search(oSrchParams): any { ...}
```

And the call became

```
this._searchCall.search(oSrchParams).then(
  (item) => (
    this._ngZone.run(()=>{
      this.items = result,
      (console.log("search", JSON.stringify(this.items)))
    })
  )
);
```

ngZone is injected into the constructor like the service and makes sure that changes to `this.items` gets reflected in the browser.  I may have too many (), but it works :-)